# Why do quantile function in R gives unequal count of values in each group

Tags: r, quantile

I am trying to group a continuous value data into tertile. I am using the function `quantile` to do this. following is my code

```
dd$wbc_tert = with(dd, 
               cut(wbc, 
                   vTert, 
                   include.lowest = T, 
                   labels = c("Low", "Medium", "High")))
```

Isn't it supposed to give equal count of values in each group? I am getting different count in the groups.

```
> dd %>% filter(wbc_tert == 'High') %>% select('wbc')  %>% nrow() 
[1] 143
> dd %>% filter(wbc_tert == 'Low') %>% select('wbc')  %>% nrow()
[1] 148
> dd %>% filter(wbc_tert == 'Medium') %>% select('wbc')  %>% nrow()
[1] 139
```

This is the dput of the values

```
c(10.9, 5.4, 9.1, 7.4, 6.6, 5.5, 4.4, 6.7, 7.8, 6.7, 6.6, 8.6, 
8.4, 4.8, 7, 5.2, 7, 6.7, 10.4, 7.5, 8.5, 6.8, 8.5, 9.4, 4.6, 
6.8, 10.2, 6.7, 4.6, 4.9, 6.7, 8.9, 5.9, 5.9, 9.9, 4.1, 8.4, 
9, 7.7, 8.2, 5.7, 8.4, 7.7, 4.6, 6.5, 7.3, 4.9, 3.8, 6.2, 7.9, 
5.3, 8.9, 6, 4.8, 5.9, 5.4, 8.6, 6.1, 9.5, 5.8, 6.2, 5.8, 7.9, 
9.6, 6.6, 9.6, 7, 10.1, 9, 6.9, 9.1, 6.8, 8.4, 9.6, 4.4, 10.5, 
7.9, 5.6, 5.1, 6.6, 6.5, 12.7, 5.3, 7.7, 4.8, 4.7, 6.1, 4.3, 
6.1, 11.6, 5.9, 7.4, 5.7, 4.7, 4.8, 8.5, 5.6, 7.9, 9.1, 7.8, 
5.3, 5, 8.1, 8.3, 4.7, 5.4, 7.6, 7.2, 5.7, 7.9, 7.9, 6.4, 3.8, 
4.7, 6.2, 5, 7.6, 5.8, 5.4, 4.3, 6, 4.7, 6, 6.1, 5.8, 5.6, 4.7, 
5, 11.5, 6.3, 4.4, 6.8, 6.6, 6.8, 6.1, 4.8, 5.4, 5.8, 5.2, 7.1, 
5.4, 9.1, 6.9, 5.4, 8.5, 5.3, 7.3, 6.9, 9, 6.3, 8.4, 7.8, 5.7, 
6.4, 5.3, 9.6, 6.4, 9.9, 8.9, 7.7, 6.2, 7.2, 4.6, 5.4, 4.6, 11.2, 
3.1, 12.3, 5.9, 11.1, 6.2, 6.6, 4.1, 7.4, 9.4, 4.1, 6.7, 6.7, 
6.1, 6.3, 5.6, NA, 3.7, 6.8, 6.7, 6.4, 7.3, 5.7, 6.7, 6.9, 5.7, 
5.3, 4, 5.6, 4.8, 5.5, 6, 6.6, 3.6, 5.6, 8.9, 6.3, 5.8, 8.2, 
8.6, 8.5, 5.7, 8.6, 6, 5.1, 5.7, 8.2, 5.4, 6.9, 6.9, 8.3, 9.5, 
5.4, 10.2, 8.8, 7.2, 4.8, 9.8, 4.6, 6.3, 5.8, 4.9, 12.7, 7.5, 
10.6, 9.3, 5.5, 10.7, 6.2, 9.3, 8.3, 7.8, 8.05, 9.57, 6.62, 6.21, 
5.34, 6.11, 10.37, 4.45, 5.55, 8.05, 8.31, 5.06, 6.05, 4.76, 
9.09, 9.11, 9.04, 6.99, 6.33, 9.47, 6.48, 4.46, 9.44, 6.88, 7.09, 
5.75, 10.89, 6.68, 3.64, 6.55, 8.69, 5.89, 9.05, 6.38, 11.62, 
9.11, 9.22, 7.97, 9.64, 12.76, 8.39, 6.57, 8.1, 7.3, 10.1, 4.7, 
6.4, 7.2, 5.5, 3.7, 5.1, 9.8, 7.6, 7.7, 6, 3.9, 6.8, 5.4, 5.4, 
9.7, 9, 6, 7.3, 6.3, 5.8, 8.3, 7, 4.1, 11.2, 5, 7.6, 6.5, 4.8, 
8, 10.1, 7.1, 7.4, 4.3, 4, 10.12, 4.3, 7.26, 8.84, 8.44, 8.44, 
8.12, 6.5, 8.58, 8.55, 8.82, 4.53, 9.51, 4.93, 4.42, 4.69, 8.69, 
5.77, 3.37, 6.58, 3.72, 3.09, 7.13, 8.11, 7.2, 12.18, 6.52, 7.91, 
5.69, 8.24, 7.67, 5.69, 4.85, 7.03, 4.16, 3.57, 8.1, 4.61, 5.98, 
5.13, 7.68, 5.47, 5.54, 4.59, 6, 11.62, 7.38, 7.06, 8.74, 8.02, 
6.73, 7.19, 6.36, 4.86, 6.55, 8.4, 7.76, 4.73, 4.8, 5.73, 8.53, 
4.6, 7.96, 9.48, 6.59, 5.75, 6.61, 6.49, 7.91, 6.92, 7.14, 6.24, 
12.53, 7.03, 4.73, 8.05, 7.26, 4.07, 6.7, 5.7, 7.39, 5.2, 6.61, 
6.8, 6.77, 5.65, 6.08, 7.24, 6.13, 7.92, 7.37, 7.99, 3.31, 9.72, 
8.71, 8.35, 5.05, 8.15, 5.1, 5.4, 8.8, 4.9, 5, 7.43, 10.3, 6.3, 
9.5, 6.9, 6.7, 5.4, 7.7, 8, 6.5, 5.6, 9.7)
```

Can someone please help what could be the reason

Comment: Could be repeated elements?

Comment: I tried unique elements count also

```> dd %>% filter(wbc_tert == '5.9-7.7') %>% select('wbc') %>% unique() %>% nrow()
[1] 56```

```> dd %>% filter(wbc_tert == '3.1-5.9') %>% select('wbc') %>% unique() %>% nrow()
[1] 56```

```> dd %>% filter(wbc_tert == '7.7-12.8') %>% select('wbc') %>% unique() %>% nrow()
[1] 78
```

Comment: > quantile(dd$wbc,1:3/3, na.rm = T)
33.33333% 66.66667%      100% 
     5.90      7.68     12.76

Comment: Quantiles need not be symmetric since it is just counting the number of values up to the p:th percentile. I.e., the value of the data which p % of your values are less than.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that shows that quantiles are not necessarily symmetric in the number of values.

```r
# Define some data
x <- 1:10
y <-  rep(1:2, 10)
# Look at the quantiles
quantile(x)
#>    0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
#>  1.00  3.25  5.50  7.75 10.00
# Due to the added y we now have asymmetry in sizes
quantile(c(y,x))
#>    0%   25%   50%   75%  100% 
#>  1.00  1.00  2.00  2.75 10.00
# Notice how the number of values below 50 % and 75 % changes.
## Without y we get roughly the same bin size
sum(x<quantile(x, .5))
#> [1] 5
sum(x<quantile(x, .75))
#> [1] 7
## But when we add y, there is a doubling of values despite we only increase
## the percentile with 25 %
sum(c(y,x)<quantile(c(y,x), .5))
#> [1] 11
sum(c(y,x)<quantile(c(y,x), .75))
#> [1] 22
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There are 9 ways to compute the quantiles with function `quantile`, the default is `type = 7`.
Use `findInterval` instead of `cut`.

```r
vTert <- quantile(dd$wbc, (0:3)/3, na.rm = TRUE)

dd$wbc_tert <- findInterval(dd$wbc, vTert, rightmost.closed = TRUE, all.inside = TRUE)
dd$wbc_tert <- factor(dd$wbc_tert, labels = c("Low", "Medium", "High"))

table(dd$wbc_tert, useNA = "always")
#> 
#>    Low Medium   High   <NA> 
#>    143    143    144      1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>